# In node, why do some modules export functions?

Tags: node.js

In Node.js, some modules export objects

```
var Constructor = function() {};
exports.MyObject = new Constructor();
// or
module.exports = new Constructor();
```

and some modules export functions:

```
var Constructor = function() {};
exports.MyConstructor = Constructor;
// or
module.exports = Constructor;
```

When should I export objects and when should I export functions?

Answer (score 0):

One consideration may be the Module module's [caching](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) feature. From the docs; my emphasis:

> **Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned**, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be
>   executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it,
>   "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive
>   dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.
>
> **If you want to have a module execute code multiple times, then export
>   a function, and call that function.**

Comment: I am unclear about "`This is an important feature. With it, "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.`", and why, if the module code is only executed once, might "`multiple calls to require('foo') **may not** cause the module to be executed multiple times.`". What's with the "may" in `may not`?

Comment: The "***may** not*" refers to the the fact that caching is [based on file location](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats). If you have the same module installed in multiple locations (as a dependency for multiple projects or sometimes `npm install` without [`npm dedupe`](https://npmjs.org/doc/dedupe.html)), each will have its own copy in cache.